# Everything on my page becomes a bootstrap button rather than just the button itself

Tags: php, href, bootstrapping

So basically, everything on my page has become a bootstrap button including all the text - as opposed to just the text itself. I believe it is because I have included a `href` for the button but this is the screenshot of the page:

[image]

As you can see everything in each white box is full of green buttons which is wrong.

This is my php code for this page:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php
session_start();
include "init.php";
$page_title = 'Products';

$query = "SELECT productID, name, description, price
        FROM products";     

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);

print
    "<div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'>".
        "<div class = 'container'>".
          "<button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>".
            "<span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>".
            "<span class='icon-bar'></span>".
            "<span class='icon-bar'></span>".
            "<span class='icon-bar'></span>".
            "</button>".
            "</div>".
    "</div>".

    "<div class='page-header'>".
        "<div class='page-header'>".

        "</div>".
    "</div>";


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        print

        "<div id='products' class='row list-group'>".
        "<div class='item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4'>".
            "<div class='thumbnail'>".
                "<img class='group list-group-image' alt='' />".
                "<div class='caption'>".
                    "<h4 class='group inner list-group-item-heading'>
                        'Title 1'</h4>".
                    "<p class='group inner list-group-item-text'>
                        Sample.</p>".
                    "<div class='row'>".
                        "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>".
                            "<p class='lead'>
                                654</p>".
                        "</div>".
                        "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>".
                            "<a href='baskets.php' input type='submit' value='Add to basket'  class='btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg'  >".
                        "</div>".
                    "</div>".
                "</div>".
            "</div>".
        "</div>";
    }
}
else{

}

?>
```

I am new to web development and I just can't see why the `href` has caused this. I need the `href` because when the user clicks the `Add the Basket` button, the `baskets.php` has to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href='baskets.php'><button class='btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg'>Add to basket</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used:

```
"<a href='baskets.php' input type='submit' value='Add to basket'  class='btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg'  >"
```

you are using `input`, `type` inside anchor tag which should not happen. And you are getting the green buttons because of bootstrap class..
Replace above line with:

```
"<a href='baskets.php'>Add to basket</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it is like a link rather than an actual bootstrap green button. How do I make it a bootstrap green button?

Comment: Either apply style to the above anchor tag or use this one instead:

<button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='baskets.php'" class='btn btn-success'>Add to basket</button>

Comment: Thank you but its the bootstrap button that im more interested in :P. I like that one, how do I do it? Sorry, I am noob to this all

Comment: If you want to keep exact same button than replace with  <button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='baskets.php'" class='btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg'>Add to basket</button> . 
Just notice that in my previous comment i had used only two classes `btn` and `btn-success` and now used all the classes you were using.

Comment: Only problem is now the button itself is not working. It works fine when I use just `<a href='baskets.php'>Add to basket</a>`

Comment: Can you provide your code which you updated. Apart from that D14n4 has provided a solution too.